# Best Way to use SQLite in Multithreading Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sqlite

I am using Sqlite as backend in App. I have some confusions. I am using a Class for using Sqlite say "DatabaseManager". In this class I have declared all methods(to access data from DB) as static. In Multithreading is it fine to make all methods static or "DatabaseManager" should be a singleton class or should be a normal class?

I am facing problem like one thread is closing the Database after use while other thread(also accessing the DB) is in between then App Crash with message "Excess Bad"

I am using NSOperationQueue and NSOperation for Multithreading instead of GCD. So that i can cancel the operation if required.

Actually in App there is some calculation part which needs data from more then one table in DB. if i do that in Main thread the it takes time or Table Scrolling become smoothless.

Please Guide me.

Comment: try to fine about FMDB that helps you about it.

Comment: It seems reasonable to have more than one database open at the same time, so the class should be neither singleton nor static.

Comment: But only one database I am using.
static sqlite3 *database = nil; // Pointer to Database
But sqlite3_stmt *statment is local in each method.

Comment: That looks fine then.  Just as long as the class is "normal" in terms of having instance variables/methods, it will be fine.  If you need to support multiple threads you will either have to check if sqlite has been compiled with multithreading support or provide the synchronisation mechanisms yourself.

Answer (score 0):

SQlite database is thread safe. "threadsafe" we mean that you can use different SQLite database connections in different threads at the same time.
It has never been safe to use the same database connection simultaneously in multiple threads.

One of the good solution is to Test for SQLITE_BUSY

pseudo-code to illustrate a solution:

```
continueTrying = YES;
 while (continueTrying)
 {
    retval = sqlite_exec(db, sqlQuery, callback, 0, &msg);
    switch (retval) 
{
      case SQLITE_BUSY:
        Log("[%s] SQLITE_BUSY: sleeping for a while...", threadName);
        sleep a bit... (use something like sleep(), for example) // -> usleep(20);
        break;
      case SQLITE_OK:
        continueTrying = NO; // We're done
        break;
      default:
        Log("[%s] Can't execute \"%s\": %s\n", threadName, sqlQuery, msg);
        continueTrying = NO;
        break;
    }
  }


 return retval;
```

Other solution is to use serial queue:

```
databaseQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app.yourdatabase", 0);
dispatch_sync(databaseQueue, ^{
    // your database activity
});
```